# Build MSI on Azure

Tags: .net, azure, windows-installer, azure-web-app-service

I have a web project with I host on windows azure. Now I am trying to add client exe to monitor something on server (something like [Windows Tray Notifier for TeamCity](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD3/Windows+Tray+Notifier))
Link to this installer will be on my website.

I use standard windows azure web site. I deploy my project using git repository.

So the question is: can I build standard setup project on Azure? If not what can I use to build such project? Do I have change installer project type to WiX or something like this?

Comment: Do you want to provide the file for download from your website? Or what is the reason to build a setup project?

Comment: If azure is build everything from my source code, why should I add build setup (30 mb) into git repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of Azure Websites the Website projects are compiled into executable .Net code not by MSBuild, but directly by ASP.NET and IIS.

ASP.NET uses so-called [BuildProviders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to build files of different types into single assembly, generating one assembly per website folder.

Since the [ASP.NET Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is not a full-fledged MSBuild compilation, you cannot compile projects of any types or any projects that otherwise would use MSBuild for compilation.

Theoretically (but, alas, only theoretically!) you could implement your own class that derives from `BuildProvider` class that would generate source code and reference it in your `web.config` for ASP.NET compilation. But even in this case you don't have full control over the target of your compilation. Rather, the source code generated by your provider will be compiled in a dynamically linked library and there is no way (at least in my opinion) to get an installer as compiler output.

So, I would recommend you to add a custom installer project into your solution, build your installer locally (either using the standard VS Setup project or WiX if you like) and copy the freshly built installer into your deployment folder before GIT deployment along with other files.

Comment: Thanks for the briefing.  How do you like this as opposed to an external ALM tool that publishes builds to Azure?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter The original idea behind ASP.NET compilation is AFAIK to enable a sort of xcopy deployment where every folder might contain its own types of code and the website still works. That would allow web developers in early time of classic ASP to combine VB.NET, C# and potentially other languages on one web site. Everything that goes beyond that should be compiled on a build server using MSBuild or any other .Net builder engine.